# Haskell exercise

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I am trying to do an exercise and I am stuck able to do nothing I don't understand how can I use the h2 m2 s2 and what else to do. I have done this code so far which it doesnt compile at all:

```
cost :: (Int,Int,Int)->(Int,Int,Int)->Float
cost (h1,m1,s1) (h2,m2,s2) =      
    | m1==3 = 0.58
    | m1>3 = m1*60 0.003+s1
    | h1>0 = h1*3600 0.003+s1
```

The exercise asks this :

> A mobile phone company charges every call lasting up to 3 minutes to any number with 0.58 EUROS and if the duration of the call exceeds 3 minutes, then the extra time is charged
> at 0.003 EUROS per second. Zero-duration calls are free of charge
>
> Write a cost function in Haskell that will accept start and end times as arguments
> one call and will calculate the total charge for the call. Time is represented as a trinity
> integers (for example the time 15:18:31 is represented as (15, 18, 31)). The type of function
> should be (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> Float. You can assume both
> arguments are always valid (ie they correspond to correct time indications) and in addition that the
> The duration of a call is less than 24 hours.
>
> To convert an integer to real use the fromIntegral function.

Answer (score 2):

`h1`, `m1`, `s1`, `h2`, `m2`, and `s2` are `Int`s. Functions like [**`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-) and [**`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-) require that the two operands and the result are the same, so you can not use `x + y` if `x` is an `Int`, and `y` is a `Float`. As the exercise says:

> To convert an integer to real **use the `fromIntegral` function**.

```
cost :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> Float
cost (h1, m1, s1) (h2, m2, s2) =
    | m1==3 = 0.58
    | m1 > 3 = fromIntegral m1 * 60 * 0.003 + fromIntegral s1
    | h1>0 = fromIntegral h1 * 3600 * 0.003 + fromIntegral s1
```

Your function is howevever still incorrect: your first case only works for calls where `m1` is *exactly `3`, not when the call takes less than three minutes. For the last guard you do not take the minutes into account. And likely you should first start by determining the duration since you are given the time of the start and the end of the call, not its duration.

Usually guards also end with an `otherwise`, such that you cover *all* cases. Here it is possible that for example if `h1` is zero and `m1` is less than `3`, that non of the guards will "fire".

Comment: Thank you for answearing, that means I will have to do the same for h2, m2 , s2?

Comment: @GeekTraveller: to convert it to `Float`s, yes.

Comment: You may find it cleaner to use a `where` to create names like `h1'` for `fromIntegral h1`, etc. rather than litter a line of code with lots of `fromIntegral`s.